# Binding portgroup to a vm in ESX manually

Tags: esxi, vsphere, esx

how can I bind a portgroup to a vm in ESX5.5 manually without the using of vSphere client?

Answer (score 0):

You can try vShpere powercli, that's powerful!

Just an example: Remove all the existing VNICs and add a new VNIC which binds to specifal portgroup. Please ensure that portgroup is existing.

Get-networkadapter -VM $VM_NAME | Remove-networkadapter
New-networkadapter -VM $VM_NAME -NetworkName $PORTGROUP_NAME -MacAddress $MAC_ADDR -StartConnected -Type E1000